# Получить данные с помощью AJAX

Tags: c#, html, ajax

Добрый день! У меня данные находятся  в формате *.json*. Как, с помощью `ajax`, можно было вывести эти данные в `html` таблицу?

Так подсказали делать вывод на консоль
    $(function () {

```
var ReqHelper = new Object({
    timeout: 120000,
    postJsonOnServiceAndCallback: function (url, method, params, async, func) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url + method,
            data: "{ args:'" + JSON.stringify(params) + "'}",
            timeout: ReqHelper.timeout,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: async,
            success: function (data) {
                func(JSON.parse(data.d));
            },
            error: function (data) { console.log(data); }
        });
    },
    getJsonOnServiceAndCallback: function (url, method, params, async, func) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url + method,
            data: { 'args': JSON.stringify(params) },
            timeout: ReqHelper.timeout,
            async: async,
            success: function (result) {
                var xdata = result.querySelector("string").innerHTML;
                var data = JSON.parse(xdata);
                func(data);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                console.log(result);               

            }
        });
    }

});

ReqHelper.postJsonOnServiceAndCallback("../csharp/Request4Helper.asmx/", "Helper", {}, true, function (data) { console.log(data); })

    });
```

Comment: А где кусок кода отрисовки страницы? Вот там и надо вставить ajax-запрос.

Comment: @Андрей Пивоваров поможете?

Comment: А что конкретно "не работает". Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: А где у Вас в HTML коде тот самый sortable, на который Вы ссылаетесь в скрипте?

Comment: @Ella Svetlaya можете пример дать?

Comment: Пример чего, Вашей ошибки? Приведите текст ошибки из консоли.

Comment: я обновил вопрос

Comment: Хм... до этого у Вас в вопросе был код перевода полученных данных в HTML таблицу, вполне нормальный был - поэтому я и спрашивала в чем была ошибка? А сейчас не понятно, что делать? Переписать Ваш же код из предыдущей версии вопроса и предложить его как ответ :)

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ использовать Jquery.ajax например

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var requestSettings = {
    url: "...", //урл по которому вы отдаете json
    type: "POST", //Метод зароса GET/POST/DELETE..
    success: function(responce) {
      //вызовется если ответ успешный
    },
    complete: function(responce) {
      //вызовется в любом случаее 
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      //вызовется в случаее ощибки 
    }
  }

  $.ajax(requestSettings);
</script>
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: я получил данные на консоль. Теперь надо вывести на таблицу html. Поможете?